# How can I check my request body in a nock intercept but leave a single integer value to have various values?

Tags: node.js, mocking, nock.js

I'm trying to nock a route call while checking that the passed request body adheres to my assumptions. This route is called multiple times to test three inheriting implementations. The call is the same except that a single  value (`param3` below) in the request body will differ in value.

```
nock('someAddress')
.post('/path', {
  param1: [someArray], 
  param2: someInteger,
  param3: /[0-9]+/             /* param3 has varying positive integer values */
})
.reply(200, { responseObject });
```

If I put the exact value for `param3`, I can get the first iteration of the test to succeed. I can also get the test to work by not specifying the request body at all, obviously. However, if I either just leave out `param3` or try to specify various wildcard parameters such as the regex in the example, I always get the following error message:

```
[route] 404 error: Nock: No match for request POST [someAddress/path] {"param1":[someArray],"param2":someInteger,"param3":exactValueOfThisCall}
```

How can I check my request body in a nock intercept but allow a single parameter to have various integer values?

Answer (score 3):

You can add an assignment when checking the body, and check the assigned parameter later:

```js
let attr;
nock("https://url.com").put(`/path`, body => {
    attr = body;
    return true;
}).reply(200);
```